# C# Windows forms - Assigning textBox value (numerical) from local variable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

This method is decreasing value of textBox1 for amount inserted in textBox2. If there isn't enough "money" in textBox1, excessing amount should be taken from textBox3. At the end, method should update textboxes to new values, but only textBox2 is cleared, and textBox1 and textBox3 remain unchanged. Can anyone tell me why `textBox1.text = Account.toString()` doesn't assign textbox value to value from variable `Account` and `textBox3.text = Savings.toString()` doesn't assign textbox value to value from variable `Savings`?

```
public void Debit(decimal amount)
    {
        decimal Account = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        decimal Savings = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);

        if ((Account + Savings) < amount)
            if (Overdrawn != null)
                Owerdrawn(this, new OverdrawnEventArgs (Account, amount));
        else if (Account >= amount)
            Account -= amount;
        else {
            amount -= Account;
            Account = 0m;
            Savings -= amount;
        }
        textBox1.Text = Account.ToString();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Text = Savings.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `textBox1.Text = String.Format("N0", Account)`?

Comment: Please get into the habit of descriptively naming your textBoxes.  It'll prevent premature balding for future programmers looking at your code!

Comment: Thanks! It works that way. But still can't figure out why it doesn't work using toString() :/

@MichaelMcGriff Sry, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 5):

The only way you'd see those results is if you ran into the overdrawn case. If the `Account + Savings < amount` - you never change the values of `Account` or `Savings` in that case.

In every other case you are in fact changing those two values and so the text box values would change. I'm pretty sure the code you want for that branch is:

```
public void Debit(decimal amount)
{
    decimal Account = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal Savings = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);

    if ((Account + Savings) < amount)
    {
        if (Overdrawn != null)
            Owerdrawn(this, new OverdrawnEventArgs (Account, amount));

        Account = (Account + Savings) - amount;
        Savings = 0m;
    }

    ...

    textBox1.Text = Account.ToString();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox3.Text = Savings.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In case `Account + Savings < amount` textboxes shouldn't be changed. In that case message shows that it is impossible to debit. Other two cases are problem. In case `Account >= amount` value in textBox1 isn't decreasing after clicking, and in third case neither textBox1 nor textBox3 value decrease.

Comment: @Marko, if this is the *only code executing* during the event that raises this--it's not possible the issue is here. There must be another method setting the values back. You decremented the values appropriately.